# slick.js image not full width --> blue border

Tags: javascript, css, highlight, fullpage.js, slick.js

I am currently using a slick.js slideshow for images in a fullpage.js slide. One of the images isn't as wide as the slide and after sliding to that image, there appears a blue border around the whole slick.js slide div, as if I highlighted it. How can I make it disappear?

Thanks!

Comment: Try setting `border:none` and `outline:none` on images. And if necessary, on `:focus` too.

Comment: With magic! As we have to make if we need to view your code

Comment: unfortunately, it only appears in my browser window and not in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a blue border appearing when I clicked on slide sections and this was my solution:

```
.slick-slide{
    outline: none;
}
```

or if you want to just change the outline colour:

```
.slick-slide{
    outline: #colour auto 5px;
    outline-color: #colour;
    outline-style: auto;
    outline-width: 5px;
}
```